# discord bot that prints something when a user reacts to a post

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to create a discord bot that has a function called when a user reacts to a message. Based on the [documentation][1], I think that this function should output something when a user reacts to something.

However when I react to things to test it, it doesn't!

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction(reaction):
    print("someone reacted to something")
```

Am i reading the documentation wrong? and if so what should i change?
[1]: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#reaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_reaction` *doesn't exist*, so it's not strange that it doesn't do anything. Valid `reaction` events can be found by entering that [as a search query](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=on_reaction), though. In your case, you'll want to use [`on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction#discord.on_reaction_add), or [`on_raw_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw#discord.on_raw_reaction_add). The difference is displayed in the docs for `on_raw_reaction_add`:

> Called when a message has a reaction added. Unlike on_reaction_add(), this is called regardless of the state of the internal message cache.

So in your case, this would be:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction):
    print("someone reacted to something")
```